# как передать локальные переменные в обработчики pynput

Tags: python

здравствуйте, совсем слаб в python...

```
from pynput import keyboard

class B:
    def fooA():
        #something
    def fooB():
        #something

class C:
    def fooC(b):
        #тут начинаем прослушивать
        with keyboard.Listener(
             on_press=on_press,
             on_release=on_release) as keyboardlistener:
        keyboardlistener.join()
        return b

def on_press(key):
    #тут надо, чтоб в зависимости от нажатой клавиши вызывалась либо fooA, либо fooB...
```

я так понимаю, каким то образом нужно передать в обработчик объект класса b и у него вызывать методы... но никак не могу понять как ибо нельзя же менять сигнатуры методов обработчиков нажатия... помогите

Comment: Ну экземпляр класса `B` можно сделать аттрибутом экземпляра класса `C`, а `on_press` - метом экземпляра класса `C`? Тогда к нему будет доступ. Если так сделать нельзя, то уточните, что вы хотите сделать и какие архитектурные требования.

Comment: @mkkik, ну я могу, например, в функции fooC вызывать методы b... как мне в обработчиках нажатия вызывать эти методы?
есть примеры использования библиотеки:
https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

Comment: Сделать обработчик методом объекта класса `C`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что Вы хотите передать параметры в Вашу функцию on_press? А именно, экземпляр класса B?

Comment: @Anton, ну да, так и есть

Comment: Гм, ну ведь в таком случае можно же просто в функции on_press создать сначала экземпляр b класса B, а потом вызвать один из его методов в зависимости от того, что такое key, например, вот так: if key == keyboard.Key.space:     b.a() else:     b.b()

Comment: @Anton, можете пример скинуть пожалуйста, а то я никак не въеду

Comment: Ну я вроде поправил ответ. Я просто добавил вывод разных слов в fooA и fooB и если я нажимал на пробел - выводится одно, если на другую клавишу - другое. Это вроде и есть то, что надо. Но я уже чего-то запутался, плохо соображаю. Но вот on_press вроде должна выглядеть как в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделал, пока выходит так:

Добавьте импорт

```
from functools import partial
```

А в классе C надо изменить метод fooC вот так:

```
class C:
    def fooC(self, b):
        with keyboard.Listener(
             on_press=partial(on_press, b), # вместо on_press=on_press
             on_release=on_release) as keyboardlistener:
            keyboardlistener.join()
```

А саму функцию-обработчик изменим так:

```
def on_press(*args):
    b = args[0]
    key = args[1]
    if key == keyboard.Key.space:
        b.fooB()
    else:
        b.fooA()
```

Comment: @Anton, нужно еще в обработчик передавать извне объект B, а не в нем самом создавать...

Comment: @Anton, спасибо, кажись, это то что было нужно